# Getting error on Firebase - FirebaseError: Invalid segment (users//cart). Paths must not contain // in them

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Code in cart.component.ts**

```
this.cart.getCart().subscribe(cs => 
      {
        this.shoppingCart = cs.map( x =>{
        return{
          id: x.payload.doc.id,
          ...x.payload.doc.data() as {}
          }
        })
      }
```

**code in cart.service.ts**

```
getCart(){
    return this.fs.collection(`users/${this.as.userId}/cart`).snapshotChanges()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possibility I can see here is that `this.as.userId` is empty. Make sure that value is not empty, and that should resolve the issue. Because it's empty, your `getCart()` function is trying to query a collection `users//cart`, but there should be a user id between the `users/` and `/cart` parts.